# Can a SAP oData Navigation Property be used to get the Keys of the first entity into the Data Provider class of the related entity?

Tags: odata, sap-gateway

For example, there are two Entities, Parent and Child. There are 1..n Child Entities for any Parent Entities. Is there a way to set up a Service in SEGW so that when calling a Navigation Property from Parent to Child, the Data Provider Class of Child is called with a table of Parent keys so subsequently all child entities for each parent can be selected? This is for nesting a list into a detail screen in SAP Mobile Developement Kit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the meantime, we have built this functionality around the get_expanded_entity method. There is however another issue that I will open another question for.

Generally the $expand operator of oData has to be used. the oData entity should have a ddic structure that can be used to fill an internal table which is then passed to function copy_data_to_ref inside get_expanded_entityset method. This will return a nested odata result